# Export module after promise completes

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I actually want to put the "read" function in a different module and then require it in my main app.js. (I'm quite new to using promises)

[REVISED]

```
var dir = require('node-dir');
var files = function getFiles(){

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        dir.files('../sample/sample', function (err, res){
            if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    console.log('Oops, an error occured %s', err);
            }
            else {
                      resolve(res);
                      return res;
                  }
            });
        });
}

console.log(files);

module.exports = files;
```

UPDATE AGAIN:

```
//read.js

var dir = require('node-dir');
var Promise = require('promise');


module.exports = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        dir.files('../sample/sample', function (error, results){
            if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                    console.log('Oops, an error occured %s', err);
            }
            else {
                      resolve(results);
                  }
            });
        })

//app.js

var filelist = require('./read');

filelist.then(function (res){

    console.log(res);
})
```

How do I go about that? I've tried "return new promise..." and putting the whole thing in a getFile function, but it doesn't return anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What also matters here is how you use the promise. Where's the code that calls that exported promise. (promise.then) Also there's not need for the extra then there.

Comment: Actually, I took that extra "then" out I was gonna use that "then" for something else and forgot to take it out when I posted. I'll paste the revised code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## This is my code

### read.js

```
var dir = require('node-dir');

var files = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    dir.files('../sample/sample.txt', function (err, res){
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
            console.log('Oops, an error occured %s', err);
        }
        else {
            resolve(res);
        }
    });
});

exports.files = files;
```

And then use it as such on the file that imports this module.

### app.js

```
var read = require('read.js');

read.files.then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

## Your revised code

### read.js

```
var dir = require('node-dir');

var files = function(){
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        dir.files('../sample/sample', function (err, res){
            if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    console.log('Oops, an error occured %s', err);
            }
            else {
                      resolve(res);
                      return res;
              }
        });
    });
}

exports.files = files;
```

### app.js

```
var read = require('read.js');

read.files().then(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: lets say I put the first half in "read.js" and then required it in "app.js", how do I call the second part in your answer? I pasted my revised code

Comment: From my code, in app.js you will type the second part. I'll update the answer to also show you how to use your updated code.

Comment: thanks for the tip! At first, I didn't understand what you were saying, but then I exported the promise, and then required it in app.js, and then put the "...then(function(res){}).... in my main app, and now it works!

Comment: is it common or good practice to export a promise and then require it in app.js?

Comment: No problem. You can mark the answer if it helped. :)

Comment: Yeah there shouldn't be any problem in exporting promises, although you can use the second method if you want, it is just the function which is called on demand and returns the promise instead. Both are valid.

Comment: hi there, I am confused that after ```resolve(res);``` why do we need to return res? what are the differences between return res and without return res?

Answer (score 0):

**Async/Await approach**

Example for `promise-mysql` module.

**connection.js**

```
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');

const dbDev = async () => {
    return await mysql.createConnection({
        host: YOUR_MYSQL_HOST,
        user: YOUR_MYSQL_USER,
        password: YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        database: YOUR_MYSQL_DB_NAME         
    });
}

module.exports = {
    dbDev
};
```

**app.js**

```
const connection = require('./connection');

const showResult = async () => {
        try {
        const con = await connection.dbDev();
        const result = await con.query(YOUR_QUERY);
        con.end();
        console.log(result);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
}

showResult();
```

**Note for node-dir module**

I know the question is about *Export module after promise completes* but in case of the `node-dir` module also works **synchronously**, maybe it will help someone else.

**read.js**

```
const dir = require('node-dir');

const files = function() {
    return dir.files(YOUR_DIR, {sync:true});
}

exports.files = files;
```

**app.js**

```
const read = require('./read');

try {
    const res = read.files();
    console.log(res);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
}
```